# sqlite3 in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

How do I check if the database file already exists or not?
And, if the it exists, how do I check if it already has a specific table or not?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211501/using-sqlite-in-a-python-program, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449495/can-i-test-for-the-existence-of-a-table-in-a-sqlite-database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To see if a database exists, you can [`sqlite3.connect`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) to the file that you think contains the database, and try running a query on it.  If it is *not* a database, you will get this error:

```
>>> c.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

`sqlite3.connect` *will* create the database if it doesn't exist; as @johnp points out in the comments, [`os.path.exists`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) will tell you whether the file exists.

To check for existing tables, you [query against sqlite_master](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7).  For example:

```
>>> def foo(name):
...     for row in c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"):
...             if row == (name,):
...                     return True
...     return False
... 
>>> foo("tz_data")
True
>>> foo("asdf")
False
```

Comment: hmm... does calling sqlite3.connect() automatically create the database?

Comment: If you want to see if the file exists, use os.path.exists():

    import os.path
    os.path.exists('dbname.db')

Perform this check before you sqlite3.connect() to avoid creating the database if it does not exist.

Comment: Sorry--formatting code in comments didn't go well, but you should get the idea.