# need checking and padding sqlite database housekeeping and manipulate code

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

All,

**Update: based on google result and answer, I added more hints, still not finished.**

In using sqlite3 and during study of sqlalchemy, I found it is necessary to write below code for those housekeeping purpose for managing data, however, it may be a hard part for me to doing that in sqlalchemy then I turning back to sqlite3 module.

Below code lists 10 more steps as housekeeping jobs and most of them came from WEB, I doubt someone with expertise can checking and padding the missing part for it.
And if someone know how to do it in SQLAlchemy, could you also sharing it pls?

**1. testing if the database file existing**

```
import sqlite3 
import os 
database_name = "newdb.db" 
if not os.path.isfile(database_name): 
    print "the database already exist" 

# connect to to db, refer #2
db_connection = sqlite3.connect(database_name) 
db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
```

**2. testing if database file is a valid sqlite3 format**

```
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516508/sqlite3-in-python


    >>> c.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl") 
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
    sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
    =========sqlalchemy way ===============
    http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg20860.html
    import os, os.path as osp
try:
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
except:
    import sqlite3 as sqlite

def isSQLite(filename):
    """True if filename is a SQLite database
    File is database if: (1) file exists, (2) length is non-zero,
                        (3) can connect, (4) has sqlite_master table
    """
    # validate file exists
    if not osp.isfile(filename):
        return False
    # is not an empty file
    if not os.stat(filename).st_size:
        return False
    # can open a connection
    try:
        conn = sqlite.connect(filename)
    except:
        return False
    # has sqlite_master
    try:
        result = conn.execute('pragma table_info(sqlite_master)').fetchall()
        if len(result) == 0:
            conn.close()
            return False
    except:
        conn.close()
        return False

    # looks like a good database
    conn.close()
    return True
```

**3. check table exist**

```
c=conn.cursor() 
if table_name in [row for row in c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name';")]
```

**4.backup database file in disk**

```
http://stuvel.eu/archive/55/safely-copy-a-sqlite-database
import shutil, os, sqlite3
if not os.path.isdir ( backupdir ):
    raise Exception 
backupfile = os.path.join ( backupdir, os.path.basename(dbfile) + time.strftime(".%Y%m%d-%H%M") )
db = sqlite3.connect ( dbfile )
cur = db.cursor ()
cur.execute ( 'begin immediate' )
shutil.copyfile ( dbfile, backupfile )
cur.execute ( 'rollback' )
=========or========
http://github.com/husio/python-sqlite3-backup
=========or========
http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.iterdump
```

**5. backup table - in same database file**

```
   c=conn.cursor() 
   c.execute("CREATE TABLE demo_backup AS SELECT * FROM demo;")
```

**6. rename table**

```
c.execute("ALTER TABLE foo RENAME TO bar;")
```

**7. copy table to/from different database:**

```
Thanks, MPelletier

Connect to one database 
db_connection = sqlite3.connect(database_file) 
Attach the second database
db_connection.execute("ATTACH database_file2 AS database_name2")
Insert from one to the other:
db_connection.execute("INSERT INTO FooTable SELECT * FROM database_name2.FooTable")
==========or============
db_connection.execute("INSERT INTO database_name2.FooTable SELECT * FROM FooTable")

    ========sqlalchemy way======
    http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg11563.html
      def duplicateToDisk(self, file):
    '''Tohle ulozi databazi, ktera byla pouze v pameti, na disk'''
    cur = self.connection()
    import os
    if os.path.exists(file):
      os.remove(file)
    cur.execute("attach %s as extern" % file)

    self.checkTable('extern.dictionary')
    cur.execute("insert into extern.dictionary select * from dictionary")
    cur.execute("detach extern")
    self.commit()
```

**8 test database is locked or not?**

```
 #possible?
 try:
    c = sqlite.connect(database_name, timeout=0)  
    c.commit() 
 except OperationalError               # OperationalError: database is locked
```

**9. timeout to connect to database, waiting other invoker release the lock**

```
c = sqlite.connect(database_name, timeout=30.0)  # default 5sec
```

**10 force all database connections release/commit A.K.A to release all lock?**

```
   refer #12
```

**11. multi-threads in using sqlite in python:**

```
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/526618/
http://www.yeraze.com/2009/01/python-sqlite-multiple-threads/
```

**12 get conn from SQLAlchemy?**

```
   #from FAQ
    #try to reuse the connection pool from SQLAlchemy
    engine = create_engine(...)
    conn = engine.connect()              #****1
    conn.connection.<do DBAPI things>
    cursor = conn.connection.cursor(<DBAPI specific arguments..>)
    ===or ==== can out of pool's manage
    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.detach()  # detaches the DBAPI connection from the connection pool
    conn.connection.<go nuts>
    conn.close()  # connection is closed for real, the pool replaces it with a new connect

    ========and not sure if this works ===========
#from sqlalchemy document                #http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/sqlalchemy/pooling.html?highlight=connection%20pool
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool
import sqlite3 as sqlite3

conn_proxy = pool.manage(sqlite3)
# then connect normally
connection = conn_proxy.connect(...)


=====================================================================
    #****1  ： what is #****1 on above code invoked                  =_=!!
    A engine.raw_connection()
    =
    A pool.unique_connection()
    =
    A _ConnectionFairy(self).checkout()
    =
    A return _ConnectionFairy <== cls
    =   _connection_record.get_connection()
    =            _ConnectionRecord.connection
    =                return a pool.creator **which is a callable function that returns a DB-API connection object**
```

Thanks for your time!

Rgs,
KC

Comment: You obviously don't want to do steps 5 and 6 on a regular basis.

Comment: I don't think #8 works (testing database is locked by just committing).  My database wrapper commits on every transaction, even just SELECTS and yet I only get the database is locked error if I do a write (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE).  Instead, I test it by just changing a value in a dummy table.

Answer (score 2):

To copy data to/from a different database, the general SQLite approach is:

1. Connect to one database

   ```
   db_connection = sqlite3.connect(database_file)
   ```
2. Attach the second database

   ```
   db_connection.execute("ATTACH database_file2 AS database_name2")
   ```
3. Insert from one to the other:

   ```
   db_connection.execute("INSERT INTO FooTable SELECT * FROM database_name2.FooTable")
   ```

   or

   ```
   db_connection.execute("INSERT INTO database_name2.FooTable SELECT * FROM FooTable")
   ```